# UINavigationController - Keep Background Image Across All Views

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a way to have a background image remain constant across all views in a navigation controller? Currently I am loading the same background in each view's `viewDidLoad` method but this shows the background image move when navigating from view to view. I'd rather just the content of the view *infront* of the background "slide" on/off screen, but the background stay stationary. This is my current background image loading code:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"InfoBackground.png"];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
[background release];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a background image you will be using in every part of your app?

Comment: @bryanmac based on what Kevin is asking, it seems that he is talking about the background image of the current top view controller displayed within the navigation controller, not the navigation bar.

Comment: This question is asking how to get a static background on a UINavigationController, without it animating around with the individual pages.  #9447979 is asking how to globally set a navigation bar background using UINavigationBar.appearance.  The questions aren't even vaguely related.  This is a perfect example of why "community moderating" is a terrible idea--people see "close (3)" and click just to join the bandwagon, without even reading.

Comment: @GlennMaynard - (not arguing at all, just debating) I voted to reopen this.  However, I'm curious as to why you think the community moderating is a bad idea.  What would you prefer?  Isn't it better to have absolute power be placed in the hands of everyone rather than only a few?  Sure, there are some downsides (such as people sometimes ganging up to be "popular"), but I personally think that that is better than the other choice.  The more people there are in charge, the less abuses of power there are.

Comment: SO's moderating doesn't encourage *correct* moderation; there's no penalty for a question being closed in error, so you get people clicking "close (3)" whenever they see it, since it makes them feel like they've helped--without actually doing the work.  (And it's not an alternate choice--this site still has regular moderators, and I've seen plenty of questions wrongly closed by them, too.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hm, perhaps if you look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (scroll down to Figure 2) you will get an idea of what you're dealing with.  Because you are setting the background image for each of your view controllers that are being pushed into the UINavigationController, you will get that animation.  What you need to do is set the background image into the nav controller itself.

I believe `myNavController.view insertSubview:myImageView atIndex:0` should work.  If your image needs to fill in behind the content view exactly, you could set the frame coordinates based on the coordinates and/or heights of the navbar and toolbar, which can be accessed through the navigation controller's properties.  If not, just set the frame to the superview's bounds.

Let me know how it goes.

Edit: Oh, note that you would need to make sure each of your view controllers had transparent backgrounds.

Comment: This works, but can we really assume it always will be at index 0?

Comment: @WingYn Well, why would it not be at index 0?  I believe that, once you set it, there's no code in the nav controller which would move it around...  Heck, test it.

Comment: This works, but breaks animations.  UIViewController seems to assume views are opaque, so that a new view transitioning on covers up the old view.  The old view doesn't actually move all the way off the screen, and this becomes visible if it's not covered by a new opaque view.

Comment: @GlennMaynard Interesting, you are correct.  This no longer works properly as of iOS 7, because the animation behavior of the UINavigationController has changed.  Maybe one way to solve it would be to fade out the view controllers that are lower on the stack whenever you push a new one on?  I'd have to test it, and I don't have my setup with me.

Answer (score 1):

i think the better idea is place background image on window and set all view's(all viewcontroller's view) background color to clear color **[UIColor clearColor]**.

Answer (score 1):

if you want background image static then there is only one way but i don't know that is possible or not, If we put image in window and make navigation controller transparent then it's stay static whatever you will do. because we are not changing window while push or pop.

I am just suggesting try this way i haven't tried like this.