# iOS 7 universal background UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to set up a `UIViewController` in my app which always remains in the background of all other `UIViewControllers`. What I want it to do is display a repetitive animation continuously in the background, unaffected my transitions and navigations in the `UIViewControllers` in the foreground. Can anybody suggest a good method to do this?

Comment: Hi, check my answer, I had this test laying around, just uploaded to github, with animation of a cat! haha .)

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own UINavigationController and add your animation view to its background in the viewDidLoad method

```
self.view insertSubview:myAnimatedView atIndex:0
```

And make sure that your other viewcontollers are transparent.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096911/443270

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and let you know how it goes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a view controller that will have your background view and animation as your root view controller. Then make the view controller that you want to control the rest of your app (we'll call it your navigation controller). Add the view of your navigation controller as a subview of your background view controller.

#### edit:

You can't do this with tab bar controllers as they must be the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

start with a subclassed UINavigationController with your animation on ViewDidLoad

push the viewcontrolelrs on this subclassed NavController

example from my github page

https://github.com/mako34/backgroundNavController