# How to slide two UIView's. Keeping the background unchanged

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can i make the background same for entire my application. Instead of going to another `ViewController` with some animations (push,pop,rollover etc.). **I want to just change the foreground view with some animations**. Still next view should in another ViewController

For example let the two colored screens be UIViews. On clicking a button on first View I want to move view1 slide view2.

[image]

**`Anyway the background need to remain unchanged Note: With different view controllers`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UINavigationController - Keep Background Image Across All Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095968/uinavigationcontroller-keep-background-image-across-all-views)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (IBAction)btnExit:(id)sender {
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(-self.frame.size.width
                                 ,200
                                 ,self.frame.size.width
                                 , self.frame.size.height
                                 )];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setDuration:.50];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnEnter:(id)sender {
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(10
                                 ,200
                                 ,self.frame.size.width
                                 , self.frame.size.height
                                 )];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setDuration:.50];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

}
```

With this simple code I move (with `btnEnter`) `myView` inside the screen (at begin is out of screen) with an animation, and (`btnExit`) move out with another animation.

You can use a lot of animations, I choosen one.

Remember to add `CAAnimationDelegate` at your class definition.

The background is always the same. (UIViewController's view)

Answer (score 0):

You can change animate duration time 2

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            [view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


        }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            [view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( view1.frame.size.width,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


        }];
```

or

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                [view2 setFrame:CGRectMake( view1.frame.size.width,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

         [view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

            }];
```